# Weighted AverageIFs Statement Using SumProduct

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

We all know what AverageIfs does.  However, what if I want to turn my AverageIFs statement into a weighted average based on the data in another column.  Suppose that in the Master tab, each row has a quantity in column H.  As you can see right now, I'm averaging the prices in column J based on a criteria in column C.  Problem:  Each row has a unique quantity so a weighted average based on the quantities in row H that meet the criteria is more accurate than just a basic average price. Anyone have any ideas on how to alter this formula?

```
ProductHier Common Name  Total Sls   Total Fct  2017 avg price  2018 avg price
B1B1403A01  ACC - Finished Goods     2,448   2,612   99      118 
B1B1403A02  ACC - Finished Goods     3,143   3,350   165     180 
B1B1403A05  ACC - Finished Goods     709     613     162     152 
B1B1403A06  ACC - Finished Goods     206     150     123     142 
B1B1403A07  ACC - Finished Goods     1,714   1,441   152     142 
B1B1403A08  ACC - Finished Goods     253     295     142     160 
B1B1403A09  ACC - Finished Goods     2,447   2,435   88      98 
B1B1403A11  ACC - Finished Goods     2,334   3,281   149     174 





  =SUMPRODUCT((Master!C2:C5000='Forecast Calc'!D2)*Master!H2:H5000,Master!J2:J5000)/SUMIFS(Master!H:H,Master!C:C,'Forecast Calc'!D2,Master!J:J,"<>0")
```

Comment: could you mock up some test data and expected output?

Comment: Hey Scott, as you can see by my reputation, I'm not too familiar with this site.  How would I upload test data?

Comment: create a simplified version of the data in excel, copy and paste the text in the original post using [Edit].  Highlight the new text and hit Ctrl-K to format as code.

Comment: so you want to get the average price based on the common name, but wieghted by the total Fct?

Comment: SumProduct? using an extra column of 1s and 0s to act as the IF element

Comment: Yes, I want to come up with a weighted average by common name for 2018 price.  The weighted average would be based on the foretasted quantity by row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use SUMPRODUCT divided by a SUMIF:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F2:F9="ACC - Finished Goods")*H2:H9,J2:J9)/SUMIFS(H2:H9,F2:F9,"ACC - Finished Goods",J2:J9,"<>0")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott!  I have the common names in column D of a different tab.  I'd like to use D:D rather than hard code the common names into each formula. This is a large and constantly changing file with hundreds of common names

Comment: Also the condition must be met that values with a 0 in 2018 price must not be included in the averages

Comment: then replace that with the correct cell reference.  I believe it is `D2` in your formula.

Comment: If I replace the name with D2, how can I tweek the formula to exclude prices of 0 from the average

Comment: the sumifs is the only one that needs to ignore the `0` the sumproduct does that automatically through math.

Comment: Thank you so much!  What categories are H and J referring to in your equation?

Comment: That is why I included a screen shot,  You can see to what each reference is referrring.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a noob.  I don't see a hyperlink to a screenshot

Comment: There is no link just the image embedded in the answer.  Maybe your filter is not allowing it through.  Or maybe you need to hit refresh.

Comment: Yes it must be the filter not allowing it through... Does H:H referred to the forecasted sales and J:J refer to the prices?

Comment: H is the forecasted sales and J the 2018 avg price and F is the common name.

Comment: Thank you, I will make the final modifications then mark the question as answered

Comment: Scott, I keep getting #VALUE! Error.  I've updated the equation in my post.  Can you take a look and see if anything pops out to you that I may be doing incorrectly?

Comment: you can't do double loops in Either `'Forecast Calc'!D:D` will need to be one cell at a time `'Forecast Calc'!D2` and copy down.

Comment: I changed both occurances of D:D to D2 and I'm receiving the same error message

Comment: You cannot use full column references.  You are trying to multiply text that is in the title row and that is throwing your error.  You need to limit the references in the SUMPRODUCT to only those of the actual data set without the titles.

Comment: Please see the following changes I've made.  I'm now getting the #DIV/0 error

Comment: Now you need to check the data and make sure they are exact matches, without any extra spaces or unseen characters.  Your sumifs, which is not wrong, is not finding correct matches.

Comment: Dude you're so smart, hopefully I can get this good at Excel one day.  I appreciate all your help